# Question - Create method from Sequelize Reference / Node.js / Controller / Models

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, controller, sequelize.js

**Understanding the problem:**

I created a route `/appointments` where I send an object with properties: `provider_id` & `date` using the POST (JSON) + Authentication token (Bearer):

```
{
    "provider_id": 4,
    "date": "2021-04-24T14:00:00-03:00"
}
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
{
  "id": 51,
  "date": "2021-04-24T17:00:00.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-04-23T21:56:12.345Z",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-23T21:56:12.345Z",
  "canceled_at": null
}
```

When in fact I was hoping to get the following output:

```
{
  "id": 51,
  "user_id": 4,
  "provider_id": 4,
  "date": "2021-04-24T17:00:00.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-04-23T21:56:12.345Z",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-23T21:56:12.345Z",
  "canceled_at": null
}
```

The `provider_id` is in the request body of the route, as mentioned above or in the example below.

The `user_id` is in the request via the authentication middleware (When I use`console.log (req.userId)`/`console.log (provider_id)` in `AppointmentController.js` it works normally).

On line 52 in `AppointmentController.js`, supposedly, it should create the `appointment` object with the `user_id` and `provider_id` properties, which is not happening:

```
...
    const appointment = await Appointment.create({
      user_id: req.userId,
      provider_id,
      date: hourStart,
    });

    return res.json(appointment);
  }
}
...
```

**Question:**
Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

**General information:**

**./src/routes.js**

```
import { Router } from 'express';

import multer from 'multer';
import multerConfig from './config/multer';

import UserController from './app/controllers/UserController';
import SessionController from './app/controllers/SessionController';
import FileController from './app/controllers/FileController';
import ProviderController from './app/controllers/ProviderController';
import AppointmentController from './app/controllers/AppointmentController';

import authMiddleware from './app/middlwares/auth';

const routes = new Router();

const upload = multer(multerConfig);

routes.post('/users', UserController.store);
routes.post('/sessions', SessionController.store);

routes.use(authMiddleware);

routes.put('/users', UserController.update);

routes.get('/providers', ProviderController.index);

routes.post('/appointments', AppointmentController.store);

routes.post('/files', upload.single('file'), FileController.store);

export default routes;
```

**.src/app/controllers/AppointmentController.js**

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { startOfHour, parseISO, isBefore } from 'date-fns';
import User from '../models/User';
import Appointment from '../models/Appointment';

class AppointmentController {
  async store(req, res) {
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      provider_id: Yup.number().required(),
      date: Yup.date().required(),
    });

    if (!(await schema.isValid(req.body))) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Validation fails' });
    }

    const { provider_id, date } = req.body;

    // Check if a provider id is a provider:
    const checkIsProvider = await User.findOne({
      where: { id: provider_id, provider: true },
    });

    if (!checkIsProvider) {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ error: 'You can only create appointments with providers' });
    }

    // Check for past dates
    const hourStart = startOfHour(parseISO(date));

    if (isBefore(hourStart, new Date())) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Past dates are not permitted' });
    }

    // Check date avalability
    const checkAvailability = await Appointment.findOne({
      where: {
        provider_id,
        canceled_at: null,
        date: hourStart,
      },
    });

    if (checkAvailability) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ error: 'Appointment date is not available' });
    }

    const appointment = await Appointment.create({
      user_id: req.userId,
      provider_id,
      date: hourStart,
    });

    return res.json(appointment);
  }
}

export default new AppointmentController();
```

**./src/app/models/Appointment.js**

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

class Appointment extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        date: Sequelize.DATE,
        canceled_at: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      }
    );

    return this;
  }

  static associated(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'user' });
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'provider_id', as: 'provider' });
  }
}

export default Appointment;
```

**./src/database/migrations/create-appointments.js**

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('appointments', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNulll: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      date: {
        allowNulll: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        allowNull: true,
      },
      provider_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        allowNull: true,
      },
      canceled_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNulll: false,
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNulll: false,
      },
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('appointments');
  },
};
```

**HTTP / POST JSON Data [input]:**

```
{
    "provider_id": 4,
    "date": "2021-04-24T14:00:00-03:00"
}
```

**HTTP / POST JSON Data [output]:**

```
{
  "id": 51,
  "date": "2021-04-24T17:00:00.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-04-23T21:56:12.345Z",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-23T21:56:12.345Z",
  "canceled_at": null
}
```

Comment: help me still I couldn't solve the problem

Comment: This is more of a direction rather than an answer. I noticed your `Appointment` model doesn't have the `user_id` and `provider_id`, instead it has those fields through associations. Could it be when you create the appointment those fields don't get added since they are not part of the model?